# How to check if SimpleList or SimpleRecord is empty

Tags: simple.data

I got the following issue. I am trying to use the With or WithMany instruction
to retrieve a linked list of roles of an business relation via an
outer join. The referential integrity is in place on the database but
the primary key on the roles table is a composite key. That's the
reason i use an OuterJoin clause because I get an exception
otherwise .

When the query gets executed the results are exactly as I expected and
nicely filled with data. Nevertheless there are certain cases where
there are not yet roles available in the database. So I would expect
that in those cases the returned SimpleList (Roles below) would be
null, cause there is not data available. Instead Simple.Data returns a
SimpleLIst and if i expand the Dynamic View in debug then it says
'Empty: No further information on this object could be discovered".
Even if i traverse further down and i retrieve the first object in the
SimpleList, it even returns a SimpleRecord with the same information
as above in debug. Only after I request a property of the SimpleRecord
I get some information that the record was empty because then it
returns null.

To come to the bottom line... is there anybody who can tell me how to
check if a SimpleList or SimpleRecord is empty or null without
traversing down the hierarchy?

I am using Simple.Data 0.16.1.0 (due to policy i can't use the
beta yet)

Thanks in advance for reading the whole story...

Below is the code sample:

```
dynamic businessRelationRoles;

var query = db.Zakenrelaties.As("BusinessRelations")
   .All()
   .OuterJoin(db.Zakenrelaties_Rollen.As("Roles"), out businessRelationRoles)
   .On(zr_ID: db.Zakenrelaties.zr_ID)
   .With(businessRelationRoles);

foreach (var relation in query)
{
   //Get the SimpleList as IEnumerable
   IEnumerable<dynamic> roles = relation.Roles;

   //Get the first available SimpleRecord
   var role = roles.First();

   //Check if any record was returned..This passes always?? Even if the SimpleList was empty
   if (role != null)
   {
       //Get the id of the role. returns null if SimpleRecord was empty
       var roleId = role.zrro_id;
   }
}
```

---

Is there anybody who can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Belatedly, and for information purposes only, this was a bug and got fixed in the 0.17 (aka 1.0-RC0) release.